# Запись массива строк в файл при нажатии кнопки

Tags: java, swing, исключения, gui

Новичок.Только изучаю Java и Swing. цель программы - при нажатии кнопки записывать массив строк в файл. При добавлении метода записи в метод слушателя кнопки добавляю throws Exception но компилятор ругается 
fwb.java:43: error: actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in fwb cannot implement actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) throws Exception{
                    ^
  overridden method does not throw Exception

Но если убрать throws Exception то напишет 
fwb.java:44: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
  filewrite(); 
Если просто добавить метод записи в main() то он запишет. Но как это связать с кнопкой?
Внутренние неименованные классы для слушателя я тоже пробовал, результат такой же

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fwb implements ActionListener{

//массив, который запишеться
    String[] str = {"1","2","3","5","6"};
    String s = "test.txt";

    //Создаем окно с кнопкой
    fwb(){
        JFrame jfrm;
        JButton jbt1;
        jfrm = new JFrame("File");
        jfrm.setLayout(null); 
        jfrm.setSize(400,500);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrm.setResizable(false);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);

        jbt1 = new JButton("Build");
        jbt1.setBounds(100,100,100,50);
        jbt1.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.add(jbt1);


    }
    //метод записи массива в файл
    void filewrite()throws Exception{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(s);
        for(int i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
        fw.write(str[i]+"\r\n");
        }
        fw.close();
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) throws Exception{
        filewrite();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        fwb a = new fwb();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `actionPerformed` в суперклассе `ActionListener` объявлен без `throws`, поэтому вы не можете изменить его сигнатуру. Но и игнорировать выбрасываемое методом `filewrite` исключение нельзя. Поэтому нужно его [перехватить и обработать](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    try {
        filewrite();
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```